# Update Opencart Product using Custom API

Tags: python, opencart

I am attempting to update a products stock quantity value from python. Here is the custom product.php file i found.

[OpenCart Custom Product API](https://webocreation.com/blog/pull-products-json-through-api-opencart/)

Using this API i am able to retrieve my products in JSON Dictionary Format. I now want to update a products price value.

```
payload = {
    'product_id': '17641',
    'price': '$51.96'
}
urlPost = 'http://mywebsite.co.uk/index.php?route=api/product'  
p = requests.put(url=urlPost, data=payload).json()

print(p)
```

The following code returns all products with no changes made to them. Any ideas what im doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You should create another function to edit product.

something like that:

```
public function edit_product() {

    $json = array();

    $product_id = $this->request->post['product_id'];
    $price = $this->request->post['price'];

    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', date_modified = NOW() WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

    $json['success'] = 'success';

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}
```

Then the url will be "http://mywebsite.co.uk/index.php?route=api/product/edit_product"